Optimization of a python code that involves reading from a huge file then splitting by a separator then encrypting with preserving format each string
I'm working on a project when I do format preserving encryption (that includes the three types alphabetic, alphanumeric and numeric ) well to achieve this I wrote  several methods, then I wrote a method that takes as an input a file and a separator, I split the text in the file by the separator using the string method "split()" and I call encrypt method on each string ,and the encrypt calls a lot of other methods to achieve the FPE encryption, then I open another file to write on it the resulting encrypted text.
the problem is when I tested on a text file of 1 million line the encryption took 18 mins
I did some optimization things for example I used list of comprehension instead of for loops cuz they are faster, I tried to avoid operations on strings cuz they cost a lot and the result was 8 mins which is a good improvement but not enough, well I wanted to use numba the problem is that I'm using methods inside of a class and @jit don't work properly (I have some object that it doesnt know them), then I tried PyPy ad the improvement was impressive for the same file I got 2 mins 10s .
but still its too long cuz then I tried a file that has 10 millions lines and with pypy it takes 28 mins to be encrypted.
what can I do to get more speed ???
part of the code:
    def tokenize_text(self, text, separator):
        encrypted = []
        for string in text.split(separator):
            encrypted.append(self.encrypt(string))
        return separator.join(encrypted)
    def tokenize_file(self, file, separator, output_file=None):
        with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f1:
            text = f1.read()
        if output_file is None:
            base, ext = file.rsplit('.', 1)
            output_file = f"{base}_tokenized.{ext}"
        with open(output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f2:
            f2.write(self.tokenize_text(text, separator))
        return output_file


Did you profile this to find out where the bottlenecks are?

Please click edit and add a proper [mcve] with a sample of representative input and output data.

@ScottHunter after profiling I find out that the methods of ff3 library cost a lot of
28.503s ff3.py:361(calculate_p)
6.234s ff3.py:39(reverse_string)
26.482s ff3.py:394(encode_int_r)
62.073s ff3.py:422(decode_int_r)
for the functions that I build the most slow ones are the ones that I have to use lists and for loops and some string manipulation

Numba is not made for string manipulation anyway so it will be pretty slow with utf-8 string. Thus, using PyPy is indeed a good solution for that. However PyPy can be AFAIK a bit slower than CPython for string manipulation though it is good to reduce many overheads of CPython which should be clearly a problem in you case.

Now the question is : isn't your code already bound by IOs or by the encryption? If your file is IO-bound, then it is optimal based on your requirements. If it is encryption bound, then you can try to parallelize the operation on multiple core (aven though Python is pretty bad for parallelism, even more PyPy AFAIK). If speed matter a lot, then can't you use native code? All fast CPython module are native ones. PyPy can be pretty fast but generally not as fast as native code.

@JérômeRichard In runtime, the majority of the time is consumed by the encryption methods, specifically those provided by the FF3 library, though my own methods are also quite slow. CPython’s performance is lacking, and while switching to PyPy has given me a 4x speed increase, it's still not sufficient. I'm seeking additional ways to further improve the speed but haven't found a solution yet.

Then the above solution applies: using multiple core. However PyPy is limited by the GIL like CPython so multi-threading is certainly useless. Multiprocessing is generally not great due to IPC and certainly even worse than CPython with PyPy due to JIT/GC overheads. Python sucks for parallel code and I advise you to use native code (eg. C/C++) for really fast codes. There is no free lunch.

Here
def tokenize_text(self, text, separator):
    encrypted = []
    for string in text.split(separator):
        encrypted.append(self.encrypt(string))
    return separator.join(encrypted)

you are doing repeated .appends to list which according to wiki.python.org

may take surprisingly long, depending on the history of the container.

You might avoid that by doing
return separator.join(map(self.encrypt,text.split(separator)))

Please test that change and write if or how did it changed time required

not a big improvement in speed

Partial quote is misleading.  The full quote is "Individual actions may take surprisingly long, depending on the history of the container."  It's a description of what "amortized" means.  It doesn't mean that repeated .append is slow, on the countrary
